# google map fragment set on click Listener dose not work

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

i want create a google map fragment in a full screen project and then when i touch google map fragment call some function but when i touch google map fragment set On Click Listener does not work
this is my xml part and java part

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    />
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    mVisible = true;
    mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.map);
     // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggle();
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
    findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
}
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself***. Please [edit] accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Create xml layout file:

The content_main.xml contains the MapFragment as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.journaldev.MapsInAction.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The MainActivity.java is defined as below:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(37.4233438, -122.0728817))
                                .title("LinkedIn")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(37.4629101,-122.2449094))
                                .title("Facebook")
                                .snippet("Facebook HQ: Menlo Park"));

                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(37.3092293, -122.1136845))
                                .title("Apple"));

                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(37.4233438, -122.0728817), 10));
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

      googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
              .position(new LatLng(37.4233438, -122.0728817))
              .title("LinkedIn")
              .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.4629101,-122.2449094))
                .title("Facebook")
                .snippet("Facebook HQ: Menlo Park"));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.3092293, -122.1136845))
                .title("Apple"));

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(37.4233438, -122.0728817), 10));
    }
}
```

If you not understand. please visit this link. http://www.journaldev.com/10380/android-google-maps-in-action-example-tutorial

Best of luck!

Comment: I want enable setonclicklitener on map fragment

Comment: particular role that not click on map, you can click on marker. ok?

Comment: Can i creat function for handel touch map fragment?

Comment: please follow the full tutorial, or download that type example. then try to understand. you only can click on marker not map. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea here he wants to make the Map Fragment act like View where the fragment is serve as Map viewer, and he wants to make it clickable thus the click action will invoke the codes he implemented in it.

I got this issue earlier and I realize fragment cannot serve as View because the Materials inside of it are the one that supposedly treat like View, not fragment. But for the Map inside fragment, there's a trick to make it look like "View"

First you need to set the fragment for the map:

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

then inside the Fragment or Activity class that hold the fragment,

```
class FormFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener{

lateinit var binding: FragmentAddplaceFormBinding

lateinit var map: GoogleMap

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentAddplaceFormBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    binding.map.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding.map.onResume()

    try{
        activity?.let { MapsInitializer.initialize(it.applicationContext) }
    }catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    binding.map.getMapAsync(this)        

    return binding.root
}
```

As you notice, this class implements **GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener** to which will be use to make the make "clickable"

You should be able to implement the members and you'll get these

```
// This is the one that will do the trick
override fun onMapClick(p0: LatLng) {
     // Your code here to make it look like the map is clicked on touch
}

override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap) {
}
```

Then do it like this

```
override fun onMapClick(p0: LatLng) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked on the map, Congrats!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap) {
     map = p0
     p0.setOnMapClickListener(this)
     
     // These settings can be changed to whatever you desired, 
     // but because I want to make it look like a decend Map Viewer, 
     // so I disable all of these
     with(map.uiSettings){
        isZoomControlsEnabled = false
        isCompassEnabled = false
        isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
        isZoomGesturesEnabled = false
        isScrollGesturesEnabled = false
        isRotateGesturesEnabled = false
        isTiltGesturesEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Hope this can help